# Why does dev_appserver.py use so much CPU even when idle?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am starting dev_appserver.py with the following parameters:

```
dev_appserver.py --require_indexes=yes --datastore_path=/Users/mattfaus/dev/webapp/datastore/current.sqlite --blobstore_path=/Users/mattfaus/dev/webapp/datastore/blobs/ --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080 --skip_sdk_update_check=yes --enable_sendmail=yes /Users/mattfaus/dev/webapp
```

And in Activity Monitor I see that it is constantly using 150% CPU even when it is not servicing requests.  The biggest symptom I see is drastically reduce battery life and a nearly overheating CPU on my Macbook Pro. I now have to be careful to shutdown the appserver any time I am not using it to prevent these things from happening.

This started happening about 1 month ago, probably when I upgraded to 1.8.1 or 1.8.2.  Is there any way I can configure GAE to stop using so much CPU?

I am using GAE SDK 1.8.3 and here is an overview of my hardware/software.

Hardware Overview:

Model Name:   MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro9,1
  Processor Name:   Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:  2.3 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    4
  L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 6 MB
  Memory:   16 GB
  Sudden Motion Sensor:
  State:    Enabled

System Software Overview:

System Version:   OS X 10.8.4 (12E55)
  Kernel Version:   Darwin 12.4.0
  Boot Volume:  Macintosh HD
  Boot Mode:    Normal
  Computer Name:    mattfaus
  User Name:    Matt Faus (mattfaus)
  Secure Virtual Memory:    Enabled

Comment: I did some googling and I found this link: http://bravenewmethod.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/developing-on-google-app-engine-for-production/ It has some nice advice for saving CPU using different startup parameters.

Comment: Turn off warmup requests

Comment: @TimHoffman, I tried this, but am still seeing the same problem.  We've had warmup requests enabled since 2011 and I have not seen this problem before ~1 month ago.

Comment: The current dev server fires off warmup requests quite frequently now.  There is a command line option to disable this without touching app.yaml. I found the dev server was chewing heaps of CPU until I disabled warmup on the command line.

Comment: @TimHoffman, ah, looks like you're talking about `--automatic_restart=no`. This does solve the problem, but I worry that it will make developing difficult since it sounds like any changes to the code will not be reflected.  I'll give it a try, tho.

Comment: Actually I was confused, I did mean turning off warmup requests in app.yaml.  warmup requests being performed by the dev_appserver are new and only occurred since 1.8.x  I would turn on automatic restarts and try turning off warmup requests - at least to test if you problem was the same as mine.

Answer (score 1):

The heavy cpu load you are observing on `osx` is caused by the file watcher that `dev_appserver` uses to monitor changes and restart instances automatically.

As you have noticed, using the parameter `--automatic_restart=no` solves the issue but it's not great while developing.

One solution is to replace the file watcher, for example using this one (specifically meant to address the issue) : https://github.com/nilleb/fsevents-watcher

See this article for more context information : https://medium.com/lumapps-engineering/appengine-on-macos-is-a-cpu-hog-heres-how-to-solve-this-problem-with-another-python-native-9f2a6dc5c960